# How to use a loss functions closed-form gradient even when it does not have a closed-form itself

Tags: tensorflow

I have a loss function without a closed analytic form that I want to implement in tensorflow that has a nice clean gradient (i.e. i have some nice gradient function $f(x)$ that i want to use for backprop but $\int_x f(x) \ dx$ is with no closed form)

Ofcourse i wouldnt be able to evaluate the loss, but i want to use $f(x)$ in the optimization process. How could this be accomplished?

Comment: @Brian why? I know its gradient and i don't care about actually evaluating the loss, i just want to use that gradient during optimization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TensorFlow allows for custom gradient functions with [`tf.custom_gradient`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient).

You could write a decorator that would return specific gradient values for specific values of x. The loss function would not need to be evaluated.